# How to write a list of Polygons to a .shp file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapefile, geopandas

I have `outmulti` being a list of 389 Polygon & Multipolygon objects in Python. I want to write `outmulti` to an shp file and then be able to actually see all the Polygons and Multipolygons in the space.

I am stuck here.. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your list to `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` and save that. If you know the projection, you should pass it to GeoDataFrame as well.

```py
import geopandas

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=outmulti)
# gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=outmulti, crs="EPSG:4326") # if you have coordinates in degrees
gdf.to_file("my_file.shp")
```

To see your geometries in space, you can plot them with geopandas.

```py
gdf.plot()
```

Check the [documentation](http://geopandas.readthedocs.io) for details.

Comment: thanks that works. Do you know if there is any way to merge these 389 micro-zones into 10 neighboring (of equal area size) zones  ? Assuming that the whole area of the 389 micro-zones is 19447273m2, I want to get 10 (being neighbors) bigger zones of size around 19447273/10 m2 each.

Comment: You need to specify some rule on how to group polygons together and then do `gdf.dissolve(by="labels")`. One of the many options but it all depends on the goal.

Comment: @martinflies https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394025/how-to-merge-neighbor-polygons-up-to-a-specific-area-size-in-python
Here I actually make it more clear.